# How to rebuild only a small range of MVN modules with their direct dependencies without having to build the whole project

Tags: maven

I am working on a huge Maven project with multiple modules and multiple APIs.
My mvn depndency tree looks like this:

```
|- REST_API  <== important
|   |- moduleA
|   |- moduleB  <== important
|   |   |- TinyComponent  <== important
|   |   |    |
|   |   |     - Some_other_sub_module. <== important
|   |    - ...
|    - ...
|- GraphQL_API
|   |- moduleB
|   |   |- TinyComponent  
|   |    - ...
|    - ...
 - ...
```

Now, just for development purposes and tests, when I make some small change in "TinyComponent" I would like to recompile only this single module and all dependencies between the "REST_API" and "TinyComponent" modules. In the above case it would be:

- TinyComponent
- moduleB
- REST_API

because of the performance I don't want to recompile all of the "REST_API" dependencies, like "moduleA", and all of the modules which depends on my "TinyComponent" like "GraphQL_API".

In summary, my goal is to only give mvn a certain range of libraries from to, like TinyComponent..REST_API, without knowing what modules are along the way and only installing the dependencies that are necessary.

Such a possibility would significantly speed up the testing of some small code fixes in a situation when building full sources takes several minutes.

Comment: Do you have unit/integration tests?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot specify such a path, but you can use the `-am` or `-amd` switches to just build parts of your project.

Furthermore, with a strong build server and parallel builds, you can usually speed up builds a lot.